Do countries typically allow or refuse consular access for dual nationals?
I'm curious if there's some kind of survey on this matter: do countries typically allow or refuse consular access to dual nationals when they are arrested?
(If the Q is not clear: say Joe is a dual national of countries X and Y, and he's arrested by Y. Is country X entitled to consular access to Joe? And if it's not an entitlement as such, is it nonetheless usually granted? Or is it typically refused by Y? If international law has little to say about this situation, is there some kind of survey that divides countries between those who typically allow vs those that don't allow consular access to dual citizens?)

I know China has been known to refuse to allow dual citizens of China and another country when they get arrested in China, by claiming they don't recognize dual citizenships.

@nick012000: presumably (all) other countries that reject dual citizenship will have the same position. So I'm interested mostly in the rest.

A bit more googling found part of the answer https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_Nationality_Rule although the name wasn't obvious.

This is an interesting question but your link to the master nationality rule seems to provide most of an answer. Maybe you can look into that and then formulate which questions still remain open.

It surely depends on the nationalities involved.  If the countries have good relations, they are far more likely to allow at least some limited consular access as a courtesy.  If not, it would be correspondingly less likely.  In a situation where good will prevails, the nature of the accused's relationship to the two countries may also play a role.  If, for example, the accused does not have any significant ties to the arresting country nor speak its language, the value of consular assistance will be greater; in the opposite situation, there may be little point to consular assistance.
